# How to add Dynamic Columns in JQuery Server side DataTable

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datatables

How to add Dynamic Columns in JQuery **Server side DataTable**. 
Is there any Events from where I can Overwrite Columns information?

***Requirements:*** we have more than 250000 data so we had implemented Server Side Data Table and its working fine but problem is in our application No of columns is not fixed its depends on user Authorization. 
So we have to implement a server side data table with Dynamic columns.

Comment: if you are using Jquery DataTable then look at this fiddle to set column names dynamic https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/oLrgjrvd/83/